# DJANGO | Cómo poner campo selección de fecha en formulario de administrador

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Error al poner campo de selección de fecha en el administrador. El campo lo he llamado selectfecha:
¿Cómo se puede poner un **campo de selección de fecha en el administrador**?

```
from django.db import models
from applications.dispositivo.models import Dispositivo 

# Create your models here.
class Consumible(models.Model):
    CONSUMABLE_TYPE_CHOICE = (
        ('0','Batería'),
    )
    #name = models.CharField('Nombre',max_length=50,null=True)
    tipo_consumible = models.CharField('TipoConsumible', max_length=1, choices=CONSUMABLE_TYPE_CHOICE,null=True)
    marca = models.CharField('Marcha',max_length=50,null=True)
    modelo = models.CharField('Modelo',max_length=50,null=True)
    cons_numserie = models.CharField('NºSerie',max_length=100,null=True)
    disp_numserie = models.ForeignKey(Dispositivo, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    selectfecha = DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

    class meta:
        verbose_name = 'Consumible'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Consumibles'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cons_numserie
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu problema, quieres un select de fechas? Y que se pueda seleccionar entre ellas?

Comment: Hola. Un selector de fecha y hora.

Comment: Si quieres guardar fechas y horas utiliza el campo `DateTimeField`, pero según entiendo quieres un `<select>` de fechas ya preestablecidas verdad?

Comment: Eso es, y la hora actual no me vale, ya que puedo necesitar poner una fecha de otro día que no sea hoy.

Comment: Con solo poner el campo `DateTimeField` en el admin, podrás poner la hora y fecha que quieras.

Comment: ¿Por ejemplo así? fecha_colocacion = models.DateTimeField ('FechaColocacion',null=True)

Comment: Si, y podrás poner la fecha y hora que quieras.

Comment: Funciona perfecto. Gracias Julio Cesar.

Comment: De nada, un gusto ayudarte!